# Making sure rails queries generate the correct SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

A friend of mine asked me to check his website to see what could be wrong. Something was taking a long time (so nginx was returning a 502 error). After spending some time debugging, I found this:

```
User.all.take(10)
```

I had previously checked in the repo, and I was running it locally and everything was working correctly. The problem is: He had like 10m of users, and that query was loading all of them into memory (instead of doing the pagination on the database).

After fixing something, you should usually write a unite test to make sure that bug does not appear again. Now, my question is:

How can I make sure something like that does not happen again?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `Rails` version prior to `4.0.2` the `take` method may behave a bit differently since the `take` method was [not yet introduced](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1379375f93c53d4c49fa8592b6117c3ade263f2e) into `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

The way it behaved prior to 4.0.2 was getting the whole `User.all` array and running the Ruby arrays `take` method to get 10 elements from the array which is so inefficient and causing that `Bad Gateway`. It generates the following query.

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"
```

The new take method introduced in `Rails 4.0.2` is more like an alias to the `limit` method. It will generate the following query

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 10
```

**So for an older Rails version just use the `limit` method**

```
User.limit(10).all
```

---

P.S. I assumed you are using an older rails version since this is the most logical explanation of the behavior happening. Also that your website has 10 million users so it must have been up for a long time now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the gem, bullet.

https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

It helps to detect inefficient queries like N+1 query. It simply alerts on a browser when opening the page that calls such query.

And there are some configurations, please see:

https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet#configuration

Hope it helps!

Comment: Although this isn't an N+1 query or an eager loading issue.